# Python POST request encoding

Tags: python, encoding, header, utf8-decode, http-post

here's the situation, i'm sending POST requests and trying to fetch the response with Python
problem is that it distorts non latin letters, which doesn't happen when i fetch the same page with direct link (with no search results), but POST requests wont generate a link

here's what i do:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
url = 'http://donelaitis.vdu.lt/main_helper.php?id=4&nr=1_2_11'
data = 'q=bus&ieskoti=true&lang1=en&lang2=en+-%3E+lt+%28+71813+lygiagre%C4%8Di%C5%B3+sakini%C5%B3+%29&lentele=vertikalus&reg=false&rodyti=dalis&rusiuoti=freq' 
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
file = open("pagesource.txt", "w")
file.write(the_page)
file.close()
```

whenever i try

```
thepage = the_page.encode('utf-8')
```

i get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 1008: ordinal not in range(128)
```

whenever i try do change response header Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8, i do

```
response['Content-Type'] = 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
```

i get this error:

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__setitem__'
```

My question: is it possible to edit or remove response or request headers?
             if not, is there another way to solve this problem other that copying source to notepad++ and fixing encoding manually?

i'm new to python and data mining, really hope you'd let me know if i;m doing something wrong

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why don't your try `thepage = the_page.decode('utf-8')`instead of `encode` since what you want is to move from utf-8 encoded text to unicode - coding agnostic - internal strings?

Comment: i tried decode('utf-8') as well, i get this error:

    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' can't decode bytes in position 7281-7282: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 1):

Two things. Firstly, you don't want to encode the response, you want to decode it:

```
thepage = the_page.decode('utf-8')
```

And secondly, you don't want to set the header on the response, you set it on the request, using the `add_header` method:

```
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8')
```

Comment: when i add header to the request, it returns page with no search results.
i want to change response header 'text/html;charset=utf-8' to 'text/html', bacause that additional charset=utf-8 may be causing the problem, no?

Comment: What could it possibly mean to change the header of a response you've already read? I don't understand at all.

Comment: well, i mean to somehow retrieve the response withOUT that encoding line... not sure tho if that could help or is it technically posibble at all