# Sending JSON with utf-8 characters via robot+python-2.7 into API

Tags: json, python-2.7, utf-8, robotframework

I am having a problem of using robot framework + python2.7 to send utf-8 letters (ie. ü, ä, ó, 女, etc...) into an API that forwards the data into a database. it seems that the problem is on python side. I can't change the python version into 3.x for it may break the robot framework.
Question is how can I send utf-8 characters into the API with python 2.7?

Here's the part in the .py file i've been working on:

```
            url = u"http://localhost:port/api/path/here?stuff=123"
            jsondata = jsondata.encode('utf8', 'strict')
            request = Request(url, data=jsondata)
            request.add_header("content-type","application/json; charset=utf-8")
            response = urlopen(request)  #the line 85
            data = response.read().decode(u'UTF-8')
```

Here is the error when I run the python script by itself:

> File "script.py", line 85, in send_row
>       response = urlopen(request)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
>       '_open', req)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1244, in http_open
>       return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1211, in do_open
>       h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1017, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 868, in _send_output
>       self.send(message_body)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 840, in send
>       self.sock.sendall(data)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in
>   position 152: ordinal not in range(128)

I can make it function by replacing the first jsondata encoding into ('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'), however the data in database is then xml-replaced, and they should be visible as utf-8 characters.

I also found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464083/python-post-request-encoding) but the problem there is on the next line of code, not to mention none of the answers is an accepted answer.

Comment: Have you checked if your .py file is stored as an UTF-8 encoded text file?

Comment: Have you tried using [`urllib.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to encode `jsondata` instead of `.encode()`? That's what the [`urlopen` docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) tell you to do.

Comment: I checked the file encoding and it was UTF-8. I also tried urlencode() but the structure of the JSON data went completely bonkers, so the api cannot understand it.

Comment: I see this is old but i am facing this issue now , is there a solution for it ?